# Adding new objects to an ArrayList using a constructor with an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

i am doing one of the last ex of the java-programming.mooc.fi PART 7 Recipe search (4 parts). Im almost finished but something its wrong when I initiate the instances for the object Recetas.
For some reason each instance is OK but "ingredientes" its overwritten with the new data in all the instances. pls find below the code and thanks in advance for your help!!

The problem its here:

```
    public ArrayList<ReceiptAdmin> FileToRecetas(){
    ArrayList <String> ingredientes = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 1;
    String nombreReceta = "";
    int tiempo = 0;
    for (String data : fileToArray){
        if (data.equals("")){
            //System.out.println(ingredientes);
            recetas.add(new ReceiptAdmin(nombreReceta, tiempo, ingredientes));
            //System.out.println(recetas);
            i = 1;
            ingredientes.clear();
            continue;
            }   
        if (i==1){
            nombreReceta = data;
        }
        if (i==2){
            tiempo = Integer.valueOf(data);                              
        } 
        if (i > 2){
            ingredientes.add(data);         
        }
        i++;
    }
    //System.out.println(ingredientes);
    //System.out.println(ingredientes);
    this.recetas.add(new ReceiptAdmin(nombreReceta, tiempo, ingredientes));
    //System.out.println(recetas);
    return recetas;
    }
```

the output for testing is :

Pancake dough, cooking time: 60[tofu, rice, water, carrot, cucumber, avocado, wasabi],

Meatballs, cooking time: 20[tofu, rice, water, carrot, cucumber, avocado, wasabi],

Tofu rolls, cooking time: 30[tofu, rice, water, carrot, cucumber, avocado, wasabi]

All tofu ingredients!!

UserInterface.java
https://pastebin.com/twvXv04j

recipes.txt
https://pastebin.com/Nwz1RJa7

RecipeAdmin.java
https://pastebin.com/1TEYssgS

RecipeSearch.java
https://pastebin.com/4MbsGeYz

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayList <String> ingredientes = new ArrayList<>();
```

needs to be in *every loop.*  You can't just clear the list and start over, you have to make a *new list.*

The simplest fix is to replace `ingredientes.clear()` with `ingredientes = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are over writing the same ArrayList. To solve this issue you need to re initialize ingredients reference variable with a new ArrayList object every time.

**Refactor the code like below.**

```
if (data.equals("")){
         
            recetas.add(new ReceiptAdmin(nombreReceta, tiempo, ingredientes));
            i = 1;
            ArrayList <String> ingredientes = new ArrayList<>();//Change ingredients.clear() to re initializing a new list with new ArrayList<>().
            continue;

 }
```